# is there a way to make E911 call and also end call using adb command?

Tags: command, adb

is there a way to make E911 call and also end call using adb command?

I have tried `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:55555` but it does not work for E911 emergency calls. Also disconnect call with keyevent 6 not working.

Please let me know if any direct commands to make 911 calls and disconnect the same call. Thanks.

Regards,
Nandy